# StackExchange PasteBin

Tags: feature-request

Does StackExchange have or plan to have a place where users can upload large snippets of code, like [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/)?

Often I find great questions or answers that are a bit difficult to follow without having the schema deployed to a sandbox you can play around with. Though you'd want the meat of a question or answer to be on the main site, it would be great to have any supporting code also available off to the side in some kind of repository.

For example, in developing [my answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4776/how-to-get-text-for-default-language/4778#4778) to [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4776/how-to-get-text-for-default-language/) I wrote up the required schema from the images provided in the question.  I wouldn't want to post that schema and clutter up my answer, but I would want to link to it so that someone else could come along, quickly deploy the schema, and either get working on their own solution or tweak mine.

The advantages of having a "paste bin" for StackExchange are:

1. Posting code snippets to the bin can be limited by reputation.
2. Snippets can be associated with the users that created them and linked to multiple questions and answers.
3. Users can trust the snippets will stay there, instead of trusting a third party.
4. Questions that require or benefit from large blocks of supporting code are more likely to get great, specific answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the answer is ... that's already been asked over at the stackexchange grand central here:

[Offer a Stack Exchange-brand "pastebin"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70043/a-stack-exchange-brand-pastebin)

There's a full commentary there, so .. if you have further thoughts here you can leave them here and I can help further, perhaps.